# Ubuntu 12.04 Missing Close, Minimize and Maximize Button after Update and Upgrade

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, compiz, metacity

I just do update and upgrade, but I miss close, minimize and maximize button along with top border title bar after that.

I did `metacity --replace` and `unity --reset`, It didn't work for me.

Also, I set in the **gconf-editor** default metacity>general to `close, minimize, maximize:`

and it didn't work.

The last, I unchecked **windows decoration** in **Compiz**, and it didn't work too.

Any help will be highly appreciated, and I attach a screenshot of a window without the title bar as one example of my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this works:
try this:

```
gtk-window-decorator --replace
```

Comment: I tried it before, it doesn't work at this time.

Comment: I updated to 14.04, and the problem still presents, missing title bar on some window application such as terminal, skype and other.

Comment: why did you update to an unstable version. it has to be buggy. I researched about your system drivers but Intel stopped driver support of 12.04. try this link https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads.
try to install a stable version like 13.10, the drivers are available. My system with NVIDIA has these types of problem initially. but when new version of updated drivers came, it got resolved.

Comment: However, it is solved after upgrading to 14.04 and do update - upgrade continuously.

Answer (score 3):

This problem prevails only when the video driver of the system is not compatible or not installed. Check in hardware upgrade, is there any updates available for your hardware. And if not, search for the drivers for the specific hardware and install it to overcome this problem.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I think so. However, it back again after I uninstalled intel-graphic-driver, doing again metacity --replace, unity --reset and check compiz window decoration. Thank you! Love the Ubuntu and the community!

Comment: which system do you have? and does it has external graphics card like nvidia or AMD?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04 precise. Sadly, the problem appears again, I don't have title bar on some of my apps window. My machine is lenovo g580 i7, i think it uses intel graphic card. no external graphics is used.