# Unity bar and Menu bar Gone

Tags: unity, 12.10, command-line, compiz

I have a bootable usb stick that has Ubuntu 12.10 on it, so I loaded it onto my computer which is semi old because it was really full and ubuntu is nice software when it works. And all went well until I booted it up the first time and it said that the Compiz thing was missing and I looked that up on the internet and I must have typed 20 different codes into terminal, and nothing seemed to work. Can you please help? I dont know what to do anymore and the only thing I can do it open up terminal because nothing pops up on the screen. Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like you installed Ubuntu, rebooted, and now you can't get to a desktop. Is this true?

Comment: U can refer to this <http://askubuntu.com/questions/210962/window-controls-missing-cannot-maximise-or-minimize-applications>. This solution had helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you tell me your hardware because in most of the old pc wont support the ubuntu as graphics are high.
so your best option is to install **LUBUNTU** Which is lightweight & share same ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following script in terminal to reconfigure unity. It might helps you.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity
```

Answer (score 0):

if you installed ubuntu linux along side with windows reboot your PC or Laptop on the linux council box select ubuntu recovery council select Repair broken packages and let it run its course when finish reboot your PC or Laptop and the menu and unity bar will appear again worked for me!

Comment: Council? You mean 'console', right?

Answer (score 0):

if you have already installed ccsm , then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for launch terminal and type

```
ccsm
```

it will open ccsm , in that go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin , and enable it on right side , if its already enabled try to disable it and then enable it ..

it takes some seconds to configure it , your computer might hang for some seconds **don't panic**.

Once its enabled type in terminal

```
sudo reboot
```

it will reboot your PC and everything will work as expected.