# Window controls missing; Cannot maximise or minimize applications - make fix permanent

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gnome-classic

I have the issue discussed here: [Window controls missing; Cannot maximise or minimize applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210962/window-controls-missing-cannot-maximise-or-minimize-applications) - .

I have this problem for one of the users on my Ubuntu 12.04 install (installed 1.5 years ago). The problem has only recently appeared.

The solution that worked for me is one supplied in the question I reference "compiz --replace &"

My only problem is that this solution is only active for the current login session. The system reverts to the broken behaviour when the user re-logs on.

How can one make this solution permanent?

PS I am running a gnome classic desktop as per [these](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966370) instructions

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up using was to create a new user and set up that account with gnome-classic and then rename the old user to user_old and rename my new user to the original users name. And then do a bunch of file moves and chowns to restore the account to its previous state.

Not really a great solution. But the "compiz --replace" method turned out to create more problems